# Database engines Comparison - Windows Mobile

Tags: sql-server, windows-mobile, pocketpc, sql-server-mobile

What are the different database options on Windows Mobile available?
I have used CEDB and EDB for linear dataset needs.

I have heard of SQL server 2005 Mobile edition. But what are the advantages over others (if there is any)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found both sqllite and codebase to be easy to implement and install. Easier (and more stable) than the Microsoft options, which seem to be in serious flux.

Comment: Plus one for questioning the stability of CEDB. I've just been looking at a mobile project using CEDB that is in a world of pain. No concurrent users, no transactions, recommendations not to go above 1000 rows. I genuinely thought Access was the worst DB of all time. Not anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Also take a look at [SQLite for Windows CE](http://sqlite-wince.sourceforge.net/).  There are also .NET bindings available to use it from the Compact Framework.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's called SQL Server Compact now.  The advantages are that it's syntax-compatible with full sql server in that any query you write for it is guaranteed to work on an equivalent SQL Server Express/Standard/Enterprise DB.  The reverse isn't necessarily true, though.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need SQL support?  If not, look at a lightweight embeddable DBM-like solution.  I've used Tokyo Cabinet for a number of embedded solutions where SQL wasn't necessary and have greatly enjoyed the speed and flexibility it provides.  YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

We use Sybase Ultralite. Before that we were using Codebase to connect to foxpro tables. I'm not a mobile developer but I understand we chose it over SQL Server for performance and memory usage. Also we found they had pretty good support when we found any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using CEDB any more as I beleave that WM7 is dropping support for it.